# The asterisk positioning in C for memory allocation/pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, syntax

I am a beginner to programming in general but I am recently trying to pick up C.

When I read up on pointers on cprogramming.com, I see something like this:

```
int *ptr = malloc( sizeof(*ptr) );
```

So if I understand correctly, this creates a pointer and makes it point to a memory address with the size of an integer.

On the same website, in the binary tree example (http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson18.html), this line shows up:

```
*leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

This syntax was not explained in the pointer section as far as I know. Is this actually the same as?:

```
struct node *leaf = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

You may have to go to the link to see where this came from, but the main question is:

Is the second line equivalent to the first line, if so, why are there two ways to do the same thing? And if not, what makes it different?

EDIT: the origin of the lines from the website:

```
struct node
{
int key_value;
struct node *left;
struct node *right;
};
```

and

```
insert(int key, struct node **leaf)
{
    if( *leaf == 0 )
    {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        (*leaf)->key_value = key;
        /* initialize the children to null */
        (*leaf)->left = 0;    
        (*leaf)->right = 0;  
    }
    else if(key < (*leaf)->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->left );
    }
    else if(key > (*leaf)->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->right );
    }
}
```

Comment: The second line will go nuts at runtime if you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`,  especially if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(struct node*)`

Comment: They're not equivalent. For the first line, the type of `leaf` is `struct node**`. It uses `*leaf` to get another variable of type `struct node*` (and then performs the operation of the second line).

Comment: So the first line declares *leaf as a pointer to a struct?

Comment: The first line does not _declare_ anything. It _uses_ `*leaf` as a pointer to a struct (`leaf` is declared as a pointer to a pointer to a struct a few lines earlier). The second line declares a pointer to a struct.

Comment: @Dan, that would just delay the inevitable. I'm taking a course right now @ a school that prides itself in Java for starter programming. These kids are having their brains turned inside out right now. The problem is they are aware of higher level languages and are impatient and uninterested in C. I, on the other hand, started with C and am probably a better programmer for it.

Comment: Alright let's see if I understand: leaf is declared earlier as a pointer to a pointer of type struct called node, and the *leaf is used as a pointer to that struct. I will edit the question with the first couple lines to make it easier to see where the stuff comes from

Comment: No, `leaf` is a `struct node**`, i.e. a pointer to a pointer to an instance of `struct node`.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils May be we are going off-topic here. However, I agree with you. Starting with a managed language like Java has a tendency to make the programmer reckless about the cost of memory - memory allocation and deallocation. Programming in lower language like C will make the developer aware of what is going on under the hood when each line of higher level language statements run.

Comment: The declaration `int *foo;` is a silly pun; it declares `foo` to be a pointer to `int` because "`*foo` is an int."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the line from Lesson 18 comes from a different context:

```
insert(int key, struct node **leaf)
{
    if (*leaf == 0)
    {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

The author should be <s>shot</s> made to repent for writing code what won't compile under C99; there is no return type on the function and no return statement in the function.  That is really old school programming style (pre-1989 old school).  The function is implicitly declared as returning type `int`, but actually returns no value.  That was permitted in C89, but was obsolescent even back then.  The function should have a return type of `void` since it returns no value.

Note, too — and more pertinently to your question — that the variable `leaf` is a `struct node **` or double pointer.  Therefore `*leaf` is a `struct node *`.

This is different from the code:

```
struct node *leaf = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Here, `leaf` is a single pointer — the `*` is part of the declarator that specifies that the type is a pointer type, whereas in the previous example, it was the unary `*` dereferencing operator.

There are advantages to using the notation like:

```
int *ptr = malloc(20 * sizeof(*ptr));
```

Note that there are three distinct uses of the `*` in that one line of code.  The first `*` indicates that the type of `ptr` is a pointer (to `int`).  The second is the binary multiplication operator; the third is the unary dereferencing operator again.  Since `ptr` is a pointer to `int`, `*ptr` is an `int`, and the allocation is big enough for an array of 20 `int` values.  Note, though that if I change the line to:

```
double *ptr = malloc(20 * sizeof(*ptr));
```

I only changed the word `int` into `double`, but now the code allocates enough space for an array of 20 `double` values.  Change `double` to `struct node` and it allocates enough space for an array of 20 `struct node` values.  By contrast, if the code was originally:

```
int *ptr = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
```

then there are two words to change to make it allocate an array of `double` or an array of `struct node`.

The cast on `malloc()` is controversial.  In pure C, it is unnecessary.  In C++, it is crucial.  There are many who excoriate anyone who writes a cast in front of `malloc()` et al in C.  I learned C on a system where the cast was necessary, even with the proper declaration of `malloc()` (which, at the time, was `char *malloc();`, and there was no `<stdlib.h>` to declare it for another five years or more; that tells you something about how long ago this was), so I still use it.  Most people who learned to program C in the last 20 years don't use the cast — unless their code also needs to be compilable by a C++ compiler.  (My C code is compilable by a C++ compiler, even though I normally only use it as C code.)  On that, you'll pay your money and take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

actually the line is explained implicitly in the function definition:

```
insert(int key, struct node **leaf)
{
    if( *leaf == 0 )
    {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        (*leaf)->key_value = key;
        /* initialize the children to null */
        (*leaf)->left = 0;    
        (*leaf)->right = 0;  
    }
    else if(key < (*leaf)->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->left );
    }
    else if(key > (*leaf)->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->right );
    }
}
```

The particular bit to note is this:

```
insert(int key, struct node **leaf)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To explain what's going on, `struct node **leaf` is a pointer to a pointer to a struct node.

So let's do a simple example first to understand what's going on consider the following two programs

**a.c:**

```
int double_me(int n) {
      n = n * 2;
      return n;
}

int main() {
      int k = 5;
      int dk = double_me(k);
      printf ( "k = %d, double_me(k) = %d\n", k, dk );
      return 0;
}
```

**b.c:**

```
int double_me(int *pn) {
      *pn = *pn * 2;
      return *pn;
}

int main() {
      int k = 5;
      int dk = double_me(&k);
      printf ( "k = %d, double_me(k) = %d\n", k, dk );
      return 0;
}
```

If you understand your basic pointers you will know that a.c will not modify k but b.c will.

In particular, the  `double_me(int *pn)` in **b.c** takes the address of k using the *reference operator* `&` (via `&k`)  and dereferences it using the *dereference operator* `*` and update the value of k.

So now if you look at

```
insert(int key, struct node **leaf)
```

leaf is a *pointer to a pointer to* a `struct node`, you dereference it once using `*leaf` so you get a *pointer to* a `struct node`.

So you can assign it the value returned by malloc and it will end up outside in the calling function because you passed a pointer to a memory pointer which then was dereferenced to modify it.  I hope that was not too confusing.